# How can I create an IAM policy to restrict permissions to billing/payment management?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I want to create a group with a user who only has the ability to manage payment for services - e.g. input credit card information for the account, etc. I don't want this user to have access to any of the other tools in the console. How do I do this?

Comment: Given new information, you might consider changing the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not possible with [AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM)](http://aws.amazon.com/iam/) the way you might have envisioned it - IAM enables [Controlling User Access to Your AWS Account Billing Information](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/about/ControllingAccessWebsite.html), but this only includes granting IAM users access to view the respective pages (the required permissions `aws-portal:ViewBilling` and `aws-portal:ViewUsage` carry this in their names):

> The AWS website integrates with AWS Identity and Access Management
>   (IAM) so you can grant users access to billing information. You can
>   control access to the [Account Activity](https://aws-portal.amazon.com/gp/aws/developer/account?ie=UTF8&action=activity-summary) page and the [Usage
>   Reports](https://aws-portal.amazon.com/gp/aws/developer/account?ie=UTF8&action=usage-report) page. The Account Activity page displays invoices and
>   detailed information about charges and account activity, itemized by
>   service and by usage type. The Usage Reports page provides detailed
>   usage reports for each service you are subscribed to.

### Workaround

Of course your use case is sound and frequently encountered - AWS provides a different solution aptly named [Consolidated Billing](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/about/consolidatedbilling.html), which *enables you to consolidate payment for multiple Amazon Web Services (AWS) accounts within your company by designating a single paying account*:

> Consolidated Billing enables you to see a combined view of AWS charges
>   incurred by all accounts, as well as obtain a detailed cost report for
>   each of the individual AWS accounts associated with your paying
>   account.

So *The paying account is billed for all charges of the linked accounts*, thus you need to grant the user(s) in charge of the payment management access to this consolidated billing account only, which is no problem concerning the desired protection of the resources in your other accounts:

> However, **each linked account is completely independent** in every other
>   way (signing up for services, accessing resources, using AWS Premium
>   Support, etc.). **The paying account owner cannot access data belonging
>   to the linked account owners** (e.g., their files in Amazon S3). Each
>   account owner uses their own AWS credentials to access their resources
>   (e.g., their own AWS Secret Access Key). *[emphasis mine]*

#### Caveat

While *Consolidated Billing* ensures separation of concerns and respective protection of resources/data and billing/payment from each other, you still need to share the main AWS account credentials (i.e. email/password) of the consolidated billing account with the user(s) in charge of payment management, which is an unfortunate exception to the otherwise highly recommended advise to facilitate IAM users only going forward.

- Accordingly, AWS recommends to at least *secure your paying account by using AWS Multi-Factor Authentication and a strong password. For more information, see [Security for the Paying Account](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/about/consolidatedbilling.html#useconsolidatedbilling-security).*

Answer (score 9):

It is now possible to [control access to payments and usage using IAM](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/control-access-billing.html).

When logged in as the root account, go to [Account Settings](https://portal.aws.amazon.com/gp/aws/manageYourAccount) in the Billing and Cost Management area, 
scroll down to "IAM User Access to Billing Information", click "Edit", and enable the option.

With that done, the following policy will permit access to the payment and usage activity view:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1423852703000",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "aws-portal:ModifyBilling",
        "aws-portal:ModifyPaymentMethods",
        "aws-portal:ViewBilling",
        "aws-portal:ViewPaymentMethods"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

An IAM user with this policy would be able to view and modify payment methods and billing information, but not view usage data or anything else in the console.

Adding `aws-portal:ViewUsage` to the list of actions gives access to the usage data, while you may wish to remove `aws-portal:ModifyBilling` if the user should only be able to update payment methods without making other changes to billing preferences.

The [Billing and Cost Management Permissions Reference](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/billing-permissions-ref.html) has full descriptions of the available actions.

Comment: What would be the exact opposite of this policy? What if I want to give access to everything EXCEPT Billing and Payment stuff?

Comment: If you change the "Allow" to "Deny", then add another statement to permit access to everything, that would have the effect you're looking for (see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_evaluation-logic.html ).  However - if you grant the user access to IAM, they could update the policy applied to themselves.  So you'd also need to prohibit access to IAM (or at least to the roles/policies/etc enforcing the restriction)

Comment: This worked for me in 2022.

Answer (score 0):

Create your policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": "aws-portal:*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```