# How to give IAM user restricted access to the billing information, only that part they generated?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am searching for a solution to let the AWS IAM user only restricted information to the billing information, only that part they generated.

I think that is not a build-in feature, but is that possible to be implemented with services like cloudwatch ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17473273/how-can-i-create-an-iam-policy-to-restrict-permissions-to-billing-payment-manage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a built-in feature indeed, and I don't think this can be achieved in cloudwatch.

A workaround is to split into multiple AWS accounts with one account been the billing account, using [consolidating billing](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/fr_fr/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/consolidated-billing.html). That way, users can only see the billing from their "own" AWS account, but not the global billing from the billing account.

You could aslo do sth with the tags and use [budgets](https://aws.amazon.com/fr/blogs/aws/new-aws-budgets-and-forecasts/) on it, e.g setting a tag "owner" to your instances. You could thus get detailed billing.

Comment: It is now possible to control access to payments and usage using IAM. See  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/control-access-billing.html

Comment: yes this is a cool new feature, however correct me if I'm wrong but I don't think you can restrict a given IAM user to be access only what he generated within the billing.

Comment: My understanding is that you can restrict access to some pages, but cannot usage per user. However, combining tags and AWS budgets could give sth quite good. I am editing the answer